# random(non- repeating) file generator on click of button in php

Tags: php, random, html

i want to display 5 php files content randomly but **non repeating** when clicked a button [NEXT] using php/javascript (that works in php desktop as well).

the code i used did displayed random web page on page load but i did came across repeated web page

this is the code i used for index.php file:

```
<?php
$RandomList = array();
$RandomList[] = "/review/review-a1.php";
$RandomList[] = "/review/review-a2.php";
$RandomList[] = "/review/review-a3.php";
$RandomList[] = "/review/review-a4.php";
readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$RandomList[rand(0,count($RandomList)-1)]);
?>
```

please suggest how to get non repeated files .

Comment: Once a file is selected from `$RandomList` just remove it from that list when you randomly re-select a file. Make use of [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php). If you want to keep the list over multiple pageviews you will need to use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit as I am new to these codes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save paths you already used in the [session](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php):

```
//Read visited paths from session or create a new list. 
//?? works only in PHP7+. Use isset()?: instead of ?? for previous versions
$visitedPaths = $_SESSION['visitedPaths'] ?? [];

//Your list, just slightly changed syntax. Same thing
$randomList = [
    "/review/review-a1.php",
    "/review/review-a2.php",
    "/review/review-a3.php",
    "/review/review-a4.php"
];

//Remove all paths that were already visited from the randomList
$randomList = array_diff($randomList, $visitedPaths);

//You need to check now if there are paths left
if (!empty($randomList)) {
    //The user did not load all files, so we can show him the next one
    //Use array_rand() rather than $array[rand(0, count($array) -1)]
    $randomPath = $randomList[array_rand($randomList)];
    readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $randomPath);

    //Now we need to save, that the user loaded this file
    $visitedPaths[] = $randomPath;

    //And we need to save the new list in the session
    $_SESSION['visitedPaths'] = $visitedPaths;
} else {
    //TODO: Add some logic in case all paths have been visited
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping out, i have added link to final 5th - the last page to the else part...................................... but still i am getting reps of the visited page!!!

Comment: one more thing , now i just changed                                                     
     `$randomList = [
    "/review/review-a1.php",
    "/review/review-a2.php",
    "/review/review-a3.php",
    "/review/review-a4.php"
]; `                                            to                                                                                                                     
    `$randomList = [
 "review1.php",
 "review2.php",
 "review3.php",
 "review4.php",
];`

Comment: did tried your edited version. but still getting----> **Warning: readfile**( [my-local-url-of-the-file-here]): **failed to open stream:** No such file or directory in [my-local-url-of-the-file-here] on line 23

Comment: **The requested URL /rnd-norep.php was not found on this server.**  was displayed when used on wamp. ....................... the above previously discussed code I've been running on **php desktop** enviroment

Comment: @user9616292 Hey. *"Warning: readfile() failed to open stream."* means, that the path you are trying to open does not exist. The file does not exist or is stored in a different folder. Try `var_dump( [my-local-url-of-the-file-here])` (debug) to find out if the path that is required is actually the path that the files are stored in. The second problem is equivalent. Sadly i doubt that we might help you out with those, but they are typically solvable easily with debugging